# How to stream audio_out from pc to android using wifi?

Tags: audio, streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my phone as an audio device via Wifi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/can-i-use-my-phone-as-an-audio-device-via-wifi)

Does anyone knows if is there a way I could stream the whole audio from my computer to my Nexus S via wifi?

I'm not looking to share my song library (which winamp does quite well). What I want is to make every sound that my computer does to be streamed to my phone.

The idea is to use my droid as wireless receiver. That way I could play, lets say, grooveshark on the PC and have my droid connected to the stereo or whatever.

Comment: I am merging the answers from this question into http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/can-i-use-my-phone-as-an-audio-device-via-wifi#question, mostly because that one has an accepted answer whereas this one does not (but the questions do cover the same ground).